# Creating a VB.NET COM DLL

Tags: vb.net, com

I have created a project in VB.NET, and I set "Make assembly COM visible". I have added 1 function to the project and then compiled it with admin rights.

I was under the impression that this is sufficient to make the project a COM exe, to register it and that I could consume it from within VB6.

However, when I try to add the .exe as a reference in VB6, VB6 says that it can't add a reference to the VB.NET .exe file.

What am I missing?

I have noticed that there is another checkbox named "Register for COM interop", but I'm not sure if I really need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change the application style from Windows-Forms-App to Class Library.

Afterwards, I could check "Register for COM interop". 
After compilation, a TLB would be created.

I could then reference this TLB.

That solved my problem.