# Access .dll library MODULE function in Excel (VBA)

Tags: vba, vb.net, dll, module, libraries

I have a library called PIT_math_tools (written in vb.net) containing math functions which is split up into different modules.
In this case, the function I want to access is located in a Module called geometry_ellipsen_module:

```
Namespace geometry_ellipsen
    Public Module geometry_ellipsen_module
    ...
         Public Function calc_distanz_ellipse_kreis(...) As Double
```

Now I want to access the Function calc_distanz_ellipse_kreis() in VBA.
I used the following declare statement to accomplish this:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function calc_distanz_ellipse_kreis Lib "C:\Users\path...\PIT_math_tools.dll" (...) As Double
```

So far, everything looks fine.
When trying to call that function, however, I get runtime error '453'
"DLL-Entry Point calc_distanz_ellipse_kreis in 'PathToLibrary' not found."

When using the function in other .Net code, it could be found either by using the prefix

```
PIT_math_tools.geometry_ellipsen.geometry_ellipsen_module.calc_distanz_ellipse_kreis()
```

or an import statement identical to the prefix above.
Based on that, I tried extending the Function name in the Declare Statement by the same prefix:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function geometry_ellipsen.geometry_ellipsen_module.calc_distanz_ellipse_kreis Lib ...
```

However, this results in a compiler error "Expected: Lib".

How do I get the vba code to find the function inside the library module?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The VBA syntax...

```
Private Declare Function SomeMethod() Lib "Some.dll"
```

... is used to prototype standard Win32 DLLs, e.g. Win32 API. Which .NET DLLs *(aka "Assemblies")* are **not**.

What you need to do in VB.NET is to make that assembly [COM-visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61354467/creating-a-vb-net-com-dll). VB.NET creates a typelib (*.tlb) for the assembly.

In VBA you then add a COM reference *(point to that typelib)* to your project like you would do with other COM DLLs (ADODB, MSXML etc.). And then you do your standard

```
Dim myObject As Namespace.ClassName
Set myObject = New Namespace.ClassName
With myObject
   .ThisProperty = 123
   Dim lRet As Long
   lRet = .ThisMethod("abc")
End With
```